# How to create an if statement condition that would accept the list of variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, user-input

> How to create a condition in the if statement that would accept list of variables and print out the numbers that is divisible by 5?`

```
firstNumber = input("Write the First Number: ")
secondNumber = input("Write the Second Number: ")
thirdNumber = input("Write the the Third Number: ")
fourthNumber = input("Write the the Fourth Number: ")
list1 = [firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber, fourthNumber]

def divisibleByFive():
    for x in list1:
        if x%5 == 0:
            print(x)

divisibleByFive()
```

Comment: Convert the input strings to integers: `firstNumber = int(input("Write the First Number: "))`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Get it as argument in function and pass while calling:

```
firstNumber = input("Write the First Number: ")
secondNumber = input("Write the Second Number: ")
thirdNumber = input("Write the the Third Number: ")
fourthNumber = input("Write the the Fourth Number: ")
list1 = [firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber, fourthNumber]

def divisibleByFive(l1):
    for x in l1:
        if int(x)%5 == 0:
            print(int(x))

divisibleByFive(list1)
```

Don't like passing? Use global variables but that's overkill :-(

```
firstNumber = input("Write the First Number: ")
secondNumber = input("Write the Second Number: ")
thirdNumber = input("Write the the Third Number: ")
fourthNumber = input("Write the the Fourth Number: ")
list1 = [firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber, fourthNumber]

def divisibleByFive():
    global list1
    for x in list1:
        if int(x)%5 == 0:
            print(int(x))

divisibleByFive()
```

Comment: You only need `global` if you plan on modifying the list - not needed here. The main issue with the code is the input data are strings and need to be converted to `int` before using `%` operator.